# MonetDB does not accept BOOLEANs from dbWriteTable (csvdump = T)

Tags: r, monetdb

I get the following when appending boolean data to an existing table.

> > dbWriteTable(conn, "myTable", myData, overwrite = F, append = T, csvdump = T)
>
> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
>     Unable to execute statement 'COPY 1292 RECORDS INTO myTable FROM 'C:\Path\to\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp80mc5L\file3e24401f42a.cs...'.
>
> Server says '!value 'TRUE' from line 1 field 20 not inserted, expecting type boolean'.

I've taken some code of the connector which deals with this:

> > tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv")
>
> > write.table(myData, tmp, sep = ",", quote = TRUE,row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE,na="")
>
> > tmp
>
> [1] "C:\Path\to\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp80mc5L\file3e24401f42a.csv"

When changing TRUE to 1 and FALSE to 0 and run the following SQL code:

> COPY 1292 RECORDS INTO myTable FROM 'C:\Path\to\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp80mc5L\file3e24401f42a.csv' USING DELIMITERS ',','\n','"' NULL AS '' LOCKED;

then all data is inserted.

Comment: could you please provide a reproducible example of `myData` with the `dput` function?  thanks :)

Comment: Please see code in answers section. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some need for conversion of boolean columns. In the meantime, does it work with csvdump=F?

Comment: Also, the next release of MonetDB will fix the issue.

Comment: MonetDB Jan2014-SP3 has just been released, which should be able to import the TRUE/FALSE values!

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (

INFO    VARCHAR(5),

SECURE  BOOLEAN

);

CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (

INFO    VARCHAR(5),

SECURE  BOOLEAN

);

insert into TABLE1 (INFO, SECURE) values ('FALSE',FALSE);

insert into TABLE1 (INFO, SECURE) values ('TRUE',TRUE);

> > library(MonetDB.R)
>
> > conn <- dbConnect(MonetDB.R(), "monetdb://localhost/demo")
>
> > myData <- dbGetQuery(conn,"select * from table1")
>
> > dput(myData)
>
> structure(list(info = c("FALSE", "TRUE"), secure = c(FALSE, TRUE
>   )), .Names = c("info", "secure"), row.names = c(NA, 2L), class = "data.frame")
>
> > dbWriteTable(conn, "table2", myData, overwrite = F, append = T, csvdump = F)
>
> [1] TRUE
>
> > dbWriteTable(conn, "table2", myData, overwrite = F, append = T, csvdump = T)
>
> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
>     Unable to execute statement 'COPY 2 RECORDS INTO table2 FROM 'C:\Path\to\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp80mc5L\file3e241533d14.csv' US...'.
>
> Server says '!value 'FALSE' from line 3 field 2 not inserted, expecting type boolean'.